# MVC 3 Routing question

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am new to MVC, so sorry if this is a bit of a noob question:

I am setting up some custom routes in global.asax.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Choose_your_dvd_Index",
    "Choose-your-dvd",
    new  { controller = "DVD", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Choose_your_dvd",
    "Choose-your-dvd/{categoryName}",
    new { controller = "DVD", action = "Category" }
    );
```

Specifically, I am mapping "Choose-you-dvd/{categoryName}" to my DVD controller,
where I have the following view result, as well as having the default "choose-your-dvd" page.

```
public ViewResult Category(string categoryName)
{
    var category = (db.Categories.Where(i => i.Name == categoryName).FirstOrDefault()) ?? null;

    if (category != null)
        return View(category);

    return RedirectToRoute("Choose_your_dvd_Index");

    return View() ;
}
```

I want to redirect the user to just "Choose-your-dvd" if they enter an invalid category name? (i.e. the URL in the browser changes)

Thanks!

Comment: OK, I've worked it out!
Changed to an ActionResult, and it worked!
(lost the second "return View()"!)

Comment: You should add your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code other than the fact that you should use `ActionResult` as return type instead of `ViewResult` because when you redirect there is no view rendered. The `RedirectToRoute` method returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` so your code won't compile. That's why it's always best practice to have all your controller action method signatures return ActionResult which is the base class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}

public ActionResult Category(string categoryName)
{
    var category = (db.Categories.Where(i => i.Name == categoryName).FirstOrDefault()) ?? null;
    if (category != null)
    {
        return View(category);
    }

    return RedirectToRoute("Choose_your_dvd_Index");
}
```

Assuming your routes look exactly as you have shown in your question if a user requests for example `/choose-your-dvd/foobar` and the `foobar` category is not found in your database he will correctly be redirected to the `Index` action on the same controller.

Comment: Thanks Darin: Spotted that one just after I posted: 
To helps others, the above code was slightly wrong, as var category is a bool, not a category!!